# MySQL records timestamps changed

Tags: mysql, time, centos

I changed my server time using this command

```
cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/central etc/localtime
```

Ever since I changed the server time.  All my MySQL records have changed the timestamp fields 6 hours ahead. I tried changing the time back and the records won't update.  Any ideas?

Web Server OS is CentOS

Comment: Did you restart mysqld after changing the timezone file back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `timestamp` is a session variable in MySQL. It reflects the value returned by `now()`. For more info read:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone

You can specify the default time zone in your MySQL **my.cnf** configuration file as:

```
default_time_zone=America/New_York
```

and restart your MySQL service as:

```
sudo service mysqld restart
```

Comment: Thank you I will try working with this tomorrow.  Very insightful thank you

Answer (score 4):

the timestamp didn't changed. The problem is that the database still with the old timezone (which by the time difference I suppose was UTC). The get values you expect you should change also your database timezone.

Here is better explained how to do that: [How do I set the time zone of MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql)

But basically you can change it forever (global), with this command:

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'America/New_York';
```

Or for each session with this other:

```
SET time_zone = 'America/New_York';
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I am going to try this now :D

Comment: does it really change it `forever`? Will not next `restart` read old value from configs?